# Using wordpress and codeigniter in one website

Tags: wp-blog-header.php

Is it possible to use WordPress as the CMS but all of contents will be displayed using CodeIgniter?

What I want to know also if I can use the WordPress functions by simply including this `wp-blog-header.php` in the CodeIgniter.

Do you guys think this idea will work?

Probably one of the function I really need is `apply_filters()`

Comment: fuxia, why my comment is not an answer? Wordpress is a cms but it provides built-in REST API which you can call from any framework or language.

Comment: @Ikalazety do not post replies as solutions. Unless what you wrote is the solution to the question, it should not go in the answer box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install CI as a theme or a directory in a theme. Then load the files in the theme’s `functions.php` and create the output with CI. You can use all the WordPress code here.

As far as I’m aware there will be no conflicts between [CodeIgniter’s reserved names](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/reserved_names.html) and WordPress.

But I am not so sure about the usefulness of this combination. You will not need most of CI’s code, because WordPress handles that already.

Answer (score 0):

To agree with the answer above, I think it would defeat the purpose of using WordPress as A CMS. CodeIgniter is a framework used to developed dynamic sites in PHP. It is not a CMS for displaying content. WordPress is better built for such a task. You could however build out your site using CodeIgniter.